# Proper div placement difficulties on 2x2 grid

Tags: javascript, html, layout

this is a school project. Making a 2x2 grid, pictures in 3 of them and the picture should be able to be moved from "box to box". Everything else is in order, except the lower 2 divs.

The top 2 are perfectly in line, but when trying to make the second one, they either come right next to the first ones (with a br so they're a bit lower), or then on top of each other under the first 2. I know it's not a big thing that i'm missing, but i just can't seem to figure it out.

```css
#loota {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 283px;
  border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#loota2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 283px;
  border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="loota" ondrop="tiputus(event)" ondragover="siirto(event)">
  <img id="kuva1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder&w=200&h=283" draggable="true" ondragstart="veto(event)" width="200" height="283">
</div>


<div id="loota" ondrop="tiputus(event)" ondragover="siirto(event)">
  <img id="kuva2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder&w=200&h=283" draggable="true" ondragstart="veto(event)" width="200" height="283">
</div>
<br>
<div id="loota2" ondrop="tiputus(event)" ondragover="siirto(event)">
  <img id="kuva3" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder&w=200&h=283" draggable="true" ondragstart="veto(event)" width="200" height="283">
</div>

<div id="loota" ondrop="tiputus(event)" ondragover="siirto(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2x2grid can be created using css `nth` operators.

The drag and drop can be done on individual images with a class and an operator function:

```js
(function closedScopeForDragAndDropImages() {
  var dragTarget = null;

  window.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    // prevent default to allow drop
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
    if (event.target.className == "dropable-image") {
      dragTarget = event.target;
    }
    // prevent default to allow drop
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
    event.preventDefault();
    // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
    if (event.target.className == "dropable-image") {
      var src = dragTarget.getAttribute("src");
      dragTarget.setAttribute("src", event.target.getAttribute("src"));
      event.target.setAttribute("src", src)
    }
  }, false);
})();
```

```css
.tile {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 283px;
  border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
}
.tile:nth-child(2n+3) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder1&w=200&h=283" class="dropable-image" draggable="true" />
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder2&w=200&h=283" class="dropable-image" draggable="true" />
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder3&w=200&h=283" class="dropable-image" draggable="true" />
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Placeholder4&w=200&h=283" class="dropable-image" draggable="true" />
</div>
```